# Finding an example to disprove a quantified statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Find an example of $P(x,y)$ where $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ is false ($x \in \mathbb{R})$.

My interpretation of this statement is that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there must be a $y$ where $P(x,y)$ is true. One example of $P(x,y)$ where the quantified statement would be false is:
$$
P(x,y) \equiv  \frac{y}{x} = 1
$$

This would make the above statement false because if $x$ was $0$, then $\frac{y}{0}$ would be undefined, right? At this point, I don't see a value of $y$ that would make $\frac{y}{x}$ evaluate to $1$.

Comment: Are you looking for an example or a counterexample? Title and question do not agree

Comment: Essentially find a predicate $P$ with two parameters - $x$ and $y$ - where the quantified statement would be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $P$ is not defined for every possible pair $(x, y)$, therefore it is not a statement.

However you could use

$P(x, y) :\Leftrightarrow xy = 1$,

in which case $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : \exists y \in \mathbb{R} : P(x,y)$ is false, since $x = 0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Just to clarify, if $P$ is not defined for every pair $(x,y)$, then does that make the statement nonsensical, i.e. not true and not false? And, is my statement not defined when $x$ is $0$?

Comment: If $P$ is not defined for every pair $(x, y)$, then the nonsensical part would be to call $P$ a statement at all. Right now it is merely an *expression*. Yes, when $x = 0$, then your expression is undefined.

Comment: Interesting. Last question - if $P(x,y)$ was $x+y=0$, $y-x=0$, or $xy = 0$, these would all be defined but still not false according to the quantified statement, right?

Comment: Those statements are all well-defined, and they all make the derived statement $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ true, correct.